# Android Button Listener Code Minimize Required

Tags: java, android

i have started development on android application and somehow i have managed to make a button and text on activity and on button click i will change the text on TextView.
now the problem is Android button listener code is too long and i want to minimize this code? please help is there any way to Minimize the Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button ArsalButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ArsalButton);
    final TextView ArsalText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ArsalText);
    ArsalButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    ArsalText.setText("You Done it!");
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Comment: There is no need to minimize it

Comment: use implements OnClickListener on your activity or fragment

Comment: define method in the   `android:onClick`  attribute to the activity layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to minimize this code until you have this single button. But if you have multiple buttons on your screen and you want to set click listener for all of them then this is not a good approach. In that case your code should be like:

```
  public class YourActivity extends Activity implements Button.OnClickListener {

         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Button ArsalButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ArsalButton);
         final TextView ArsalText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ArsalText);
         ArsalButton.setOnClickListener(this);

         }

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            // get view id and perform operation based on id.
         }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help i am designing an interface which contains multiple button so this Method will Help!

Answer (score 1):

In your case AFAIK for clicklistner whatever the code like adding listner & handling click is required that we need to do, and in that case no need to minimize
As per my opinion in your code optimize  is possible only in case if you are not using Button Instance anywhere thn give direct click event to View instance as setOnClickListner is view method

***Below three different way you can give it you can use which ever you find minimized/optimized.***

```
// if button or textview instance is not required any where outside than
        // Button ArsalButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ArsalButton);
        //final TextView ArsalText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ArsalText);
        findViewById(R.id.ArsalButton).setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.ArsalText)).ArsalText.setText("You Done it!");

                    }
                }
        );
```

***Second way is like implement onlclick listner interface & handle click***

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements Button.OnClickListener {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            findViewById(R.id.ArsalButton).setOnClickListener(this);
            // if button or textview instance is not required any where outside than
            // Button ArsalButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ArsalButton);
            //final TextView ArsalText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ArsalText);
            findViewById(R.id.ArsalButton).setOnClickListener(
                    new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {


                        }
                    }
            );

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.ArsalText)).ArsalText.setText("You Done it!");
        }
    }
```

***Another ways is like give click event in XML Button***

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        public void onArsalButtonClick(View view) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.ArsalText)).ArsalText.setText("You Done it!");
        }

    }

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/ArsalButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onArsalButtonClick"
        android:text="ArsalButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to minimize it. However, you have alternatives to it:

To set the listener in the xml:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/myButton"
   ...
   android:onclick="myButtonClick"
/>
```

Then you need to declare myButtonClick method in your activity.

```
public void myButtonClick(View view){
    ArsalText.setText("You done it");
}
```

Or to implement OnClickListener in your activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{  

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      ArsalButton.setOnClickListener(this);   
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.myButton:
                ArsalText.setText("You Done It");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```